# yii2 assetBundle - all absolute links instead of relative

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to figure out, how can I configure AssetBundle via /config/main.php in Yii2 . The reason is, that we need to use globally absolute links for all assets (CSS + JS bundles) instead of relative.

We have set absolute @web alias:

```
Yii::setAlias('@webabs', empty($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? '/' : '//'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

So the only thing we need to change is the property **baseUrl** in class **\yii\web\AssetBundle**:

> baseUrl = '@webabs'

Following did not work for me:

```
'assetBundle' => [
    'baseUrl' => '@webabs',
],
```

because "assetBundle" is not core component.

```
'yii\web\AssetBundle' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\AssetBundle',
    'baseUrl' => '@webabs',
],
```

because Object configurator will not configure property.

So is there any way to configure "baseUrl" property globally in "\yii\web\AssetBundle"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in configuration:

```
// ...
'components' => [
    // ...
    'assetManager' => [
        'baseUrl' => '@webabs/assets'
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thanx, but not working, still relative links in all bundles.

Comment: I've checked in my app and this works: config as above but `'baseUrl' => '//' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/assets'` - can you try it?

Comment: Yes!! My bad, I had cached some static HTML. Sorry & THANK you.